# Why is my thread which is waiting on a QWaitCondition not returning

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have data structure where I want to wait until it recives data. When I call setInterrupt I want my thread to stop but it never returns.

This is my queue:

```
  BufferedIpQqueue::BufferedIpQqueue()
    {

    }

    BufferedIpQqueue::~BufferedIpQqueue()
    {
        bufferWaitCondition.wakeAll();
    }

    QString BufferedIpQqueue::get()
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);

        while(queue.isEmpty())
        {
            qDebug() << "waiting at mutex " << &mutex << "calling threadid: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
            bufferWaitCondition.wait(&mutex);
        }

        return queue.first();
    }

void BufferedIpQqueue::put(QString &data)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);

    queue.append(data);
    bufferWaitCondition.wakeAll();
}

void BufferedIpQqueue::wakAllThreads()
{
    qDebug() << "wake all waiting threads at mutex: " <<  &mutex << "calling threadid: " << QThread::currentThreadId();
    bufferWaitCondition.wakeAll();
}
```

This is my consumer thread:

```
IpCheckWorker::IpCheckWorker(BufferedIpQqueue *queue)
{
    this->queue = queue;

    interrupt = false;
}

void IpCheckWorker::setInterrupt(bool value)
{
    QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);
    qDebug() << "wake all threads";
    interrupt = value;
    queue->wakAllThreads();
}

bool IpCheckWorker::getInterruptFlag()
{
    QMutexLocker lock(&mutex);

    return interrupt;
}


void IpCheckWorker::process()
{
    while(getInterruptFlag() == false)
    {

        qDebug() << "enter process loop ThreadID:" << QThread::currentThreadId();
        QString check_ip = queue->get();

        qDebug() << "proccess ThreadID:" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    }
    qDebug() << "leave process event ThreadID:" << QThread::currentThreadId();
    emit finished();

}
```

I get the following output:

- enter process loop ThreadID: 0xf94
- waiting at mutex  0x51ab5f0 calling threadid:  0xf94
- wake all threads
- wake all waiting threads at mutex:  0x51ab5f0 calling threadid:  0x10dc
- waiting at mutex  0x51ab5f0 calling threadid:  0xf94

It seems like I am stock at while(queue.isEmpty()) in my  BufferedIpQqueue::get() method. Why is my mthod not returning to IpCheckWorker::process()?

Any help how to do it right would be very kind.

Comment: Well - if nothing is put into the queue when the waiting threads are awakened, the `while(queue.isEmpty())` loop will just make them wait again.

Comment: So, if you want those threads to stop waiting for data in the queue, then they'll need to also check `IpCheckWorker::getInterruptFlag()`, but then you need to deal with the `mutex` somewhat differently (or make it recursive) and you have also broken the encapsulation of the `BufferedIpQqueue` class. You might want to add a method to `BufferedIpQueue` that makes it 'interruptable' (by setting it's own `interrupted` flag and checking that flag in the wait loop along with `queue.isEmpty()`.  Also you'll need to think about what `BufferedIpQqueue::get()` will return when it's interrupted.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Well, is it the "right way" of doing this?  I think I will make BufferedIpQqueue interruptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is reimplementing a slightly less flexible `QThreadPool`. If you wish, you can look in [its implementation](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthreadpool.cpp.html#_ZN11QThreadPool5startEP9QRunnablei) for how it uses the wait conditions. I'd simply advise to use `QThreadPool` and call it a day, since it's a perfect fit for your requirements.

The thread pool maintains a queue of `QRunnable` instances. The instances are picked up by idle threads. The thread management is automatic. `QRunnable` is a lightweight class similar to `QEvent` - it is not a `QObject`.

`QThreadPool` is *not* a singleton. There is a global instance, but you don't have to use it. You can have your own instance.

This example is compatible with Qt 4.4 & up.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QThreadPool>
#include <QRunnable>
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <cstdlib>

class Thread : public QThread {
public:
  using QThread::msleep;
};

class IpData {
  QString m_value;
public:
  IpData(const QString & str) : m_value(str) {}
  const QString & value() const { return m_value; }
};

class IpRunnable : public QRunnable, IpData {
  void run() {
    qDebug() << "[" << QThread::currentThreadId()
             << "] processing ip" << value();
    Thread::msleep(qrand() < (RAND_MAX/4.0) ? 0 : 100);
  }
public:
  IpRunnable(const IpData & data) : IpData(data) {}
  IpRunnable(const QString & str) : IpData(str) {}
};

class Test : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  int i;
  QBasicTimer timer;
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * t) {
    if (t->timerId() != timer.timerId()) return;
    QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(new IpRunnable(QString::number(i)));
    if (++i > 100) qApp->quit();
  }
public:
  Test() : i(0) { timer.start(20, this); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  QThreadPool::globalInstance()->setMaxThreadCount(5);
  Test test;
  return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! T think I will go with your solution. Just out of interest, what would you do to make my programm work? Would you make the queue interruptable? Is it okay to do so?